# Designing a mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I need to design a database that will:

Store Users, Quizzes and Resources (like articles, books, blog posts, etc.) and Users. The User will take a quiz when they first sign up, then their answers will determine what resources to suggest to them.

Here is what I have so far, which is a sql file that creates every table I need.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_questions_answer;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_questions_not_selected;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS questions_choices;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS questions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS quizes;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Event_Table;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Congregations;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Resources;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ensembles;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Topics;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Languages;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Resource_Tags;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Resource_Types;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Authors;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Social_Media_Connections;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ethnicities;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Cong_Type;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Worship_Types;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Instrument_Types;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Song_Types;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Denominations;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Event_Types;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Parent_Org;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tags;



CREATE TABLE Authors (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(128), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    website varchar(128),
    email varchar(64)
);

CREATE TABLE Resource_Types (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(128), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Resource_Tags (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(128), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Languages (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(128), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Topics (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(128), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Ensembles (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(128), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Parent_Org (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(128), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Event_Types (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Denominations (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Song_Types (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Instrument_Types (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Worship_Types (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Cong_Type (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Ethnicities (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE Social_Media_Connections(
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    name varchar(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    type varchar(32), 
    link varchar(64)
);




CREATE TABLE Congregations (
    cong_id int unsigned auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY (cong_id),
    cong_name varchar(64),
    website varchar(64),
    cong_city varchar(64),
    cong_state varchar(64),
    cong_country varchar(64),
    hymn_soc_members boolean default False,
    priest_attire varchar(64),
    avg_attendance float,
    denomination_id int unsigned not null,
    song_types_id int unsigned not null,
    instrument_types_id int unsigned not null,
    worship_types_id int unsigned not null,
    cong_type_id int unsigned not null,
    ethnicity_types_id int unsigned not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (denomination_id)
        REFERENCES Denominations (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (song_types_id)
        REFERENCES Song_Types(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (instrument_types_id)
        REFERENCES Instrument_Types(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (worship_types_id)
        REFERENCES Worship_Types(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (cong_type_id)
        REFERENCES Cong_Type(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ethnicity_types_id)
        REFERENCES Ethnicities(id)


);

CREATE TABLE Event_Table(
    event_id int unsigned auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY(event_id),
    event_title varchar(128),
    website varchar(128),
    theme_or_topic varchar(128),
    event_desc text(256),
    event_start_date date,
    event_start_time time,
    event_end_date date,
    event_end_time time,
    registration_cost int unsigned default 0,
    event_city varchar(64),
    event_state varchar(32),
    event_country text,
    hymn_soc_member_involved boolean default False,
    parent_org_id int unsigned,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_org_id)
        REFERENCES Parent_Org (id),
    event_type_id int unsigned,
    FOREIGN KEY (event_type_id)
        REFERENCES Event_Types(id)

);

CREATE TABLE Resources (
    id int unsigned auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    title varchar(128),
    link varchar(128),
    author_id int unsigned,
    description text(512),
    type_id int unsigned,
    tag_id int unsigned,
    denomination_id int unsigned,
    Resource_date timestamp,
    favorites int unsigned,
    views int unsigned,
    parent_org_id int unsigned,
    language_id int unsigned, 
    is_free boolean,
    instrument_type_id int unsigned,
    topic_id int unsigned,
    ensemble_id int unsigned,
    ethnicity_id int unsigned,
    hymn_soc_member_included boolean,

    FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES Authors(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES Resource_Types(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES Resource_Tags(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (denomination_id) REFERENCES Denominations(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_org_id) REFERENCES Parent_Org(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (language_id) REFERENCES Languages(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (instrument_type_id) REFERENCES Instrument_Types(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (topic_id) REFERENCES Topics(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ensemble_id) REFERENCES Ensembles(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ethnicity_id) REFERENCES Ethnicities(id)

);

/* now for users and quizes */

CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    email varchar(128) default null,
    password varchar(128) default null,
    first_name varchar(64) default null,
    last_name varchar(64) default null,
    reg_date timestamp,
    is_active tinyint(1) default 1,
    high_level tinyint(1) default 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    social_media_connections_id int unsigned not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (social_media_connections_id) REFERENCES Social_Media_Connections(id)
);

CREATE TABLE quizes (
    quiz_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    quiz_title varchar(512),
    is_active tinyint(1) default 1,
    PRIMARY KEY (quiz_id)
);

CREATE TABLE questions (
    question_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    question_text varchar(512),
    question_weight smallint unsigned default null,
    PRIMARY KEY (question_id),
    quiz_id int unsigned not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (quiz_id) REFERENCES quizes (quiz_id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
    tag_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    tag_name varchar(128),
    PRIMARY KEY (tag_id)
    /* maybe link to other tables like congregation types? */
);

CREATE TABLE questions_choices (
    choice_id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
    choice_text varchar(512),
    PRIMARY KEY (choice_id),
    question_id int unsigned not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (question_id)
        REFERENCES questions (question_id),
    /* after modification */
    is_selected tinyint(1) default 0,
    tag_id int unsigned not null,
    FOREIGN KEY (tag_id)
        REFERENCES tags (tag_id)
);
```

I have never designed a database of this size before so I am just looking for some input on what I have so far. I have a few questions as well:

1. Is it good practice to make separate tables to store different attributes?
2. Am I supposed to store password hashes instead of the actual passwords?
3. What is the most efficient way to map question_choices to users? I created a table called tags that should connect the two, then somehow use those tags to find different things in the table resource_tags to retrieve what interests the user.

Thanks

Comment: 1. Sometimes. 2. Yes. 3. Yes, joins with a pivot table in the middle.

Comment: @ceejayoz to store hashes, do I perform the hash function within MySQL or through PHP/node/etc?

Comment: If you're using PHP you should use the built-in `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions. I don't know if MySQL has its own `bcrypt` function - you should **not** use MD5/SHA1.